# JDK7 TCP segment size

Tags: java, tcp, java-7, java-io

Part of our application that is writing a file to windows share ..
Recently we have upgrade to jdk1.7 and started seeing  file is getting transferred in small chunks/segments (it is causing slowness in the transfer) . it works perfectly and fast in jdk6.

does jdk7 has any TCP segment settings ?

thanks in advance.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar

Comment: Have your packet captures actually confirmed the segments are smaller?

Answer (score 0):

The settings for send and receive sizes can be set in Java 6 and 7, however it cannot be set so low as to be close to the MTU which is ~1500 bytes. It is the MTU set in the OS which determines the maximum packet size.

If the file is being transferred in very small chunks, most likely you are not buffering your data and/or you have Nagle turned off.